# Difference between 1.second.from_now and 1.seconds.from_now in Ruby's ActiveSupport library?

Tags: ruby

I was curious about what the difference is between the two.

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'active_support/core_ext'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> 1.second.from_now == 1.seconds.from_now
=> false
```

They look the same to me

```
irb(main):003:0> p 1.second.from_now; p 1.seconds.from_now; nil
2013-06-14 17:50:28 +0530
2013-06-14 17:50:28 +0530
=> nil
```

And they both have the same class

```
irb(main):004:0> 1.second.from_now.class == 1.seconds.from_now.class
=> true
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Time elapses between both calls, that's why they are different:

```
Time.now == Time.now
#=> false
```

`Time#to_f` reveals that they are fractions apart:

```
a, b = 1.second.from_now, 1.second.from_now
a.to_f  #=> 1371213500.506212
b.to_f  #=> 1371213500.5062568
```

The call to `second` / `seconds` is identical:

```
1.second == 1.seconds
#=> true
```

Comment: Makes sense now. I guess printing the Time object truncates the fractional seconds.

Answer (score 6):

`1.second` is an alias for `1.seconds`, just to make your code more readable I guess. You can see it [in the Numeric class in the Rails source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3018f4727621b6f2b117a2b5d75561127f2a8592/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb#L34-37).

Comment: Thanks. But then why are the two calls to from_now not equal under the == operator? I tried `def f; 1; end; alias :g :f; g == f` and it returns `true`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Because "now" now is not the same "now" as now was then :-D